# fonts still not showing up with laravel elixr

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

this is a follow-up question to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710815/laravel-linking-to-custom-fonts?noredirect=1#comment70617224_41710815). i am trying to get my fonts to show up[ in my laravel website. i tried changing things so SASS will import my fonts, but they're still not showing up on my website. I went to check weaqther the font downloaded in Chrome devtools, but Chrome said the font loaded a 404 error. i checked the link, and the font downloads. Very strange. How do i get my fonts to show up/

Here is my SASS file:

```
  @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

@mixin fontFace($family,$src,$weight: normal,$style: normal) {
@font-face {
font-family: $family;
src: url('#{$src}'); // IE9 compat


    font-style: $style;
    font-weight: $weight;
}
}
@include fontFace('Nexabold', 'public/build/fonts/nexaBold.otf')

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ecf0f1; 
  font-family: NexaBold;
  }

.mainheader {
  height: 75px;
  font-family: NexaBold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #dce0e1; }

.menu {
  height: 40px; }

.subcontainter-title{float:left;}

.subcontainer-left {
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}

.subcontainer {
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto; }

.subcontainer-right {
  height: 75px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right; }

.subcontainer-button {
  height: 90px;
  width: 105px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 14px; }

.subcontainer-left .subcontainer-button{float:left;}

.subcontainer-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:active {
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer; }

.subcontainer-title {
  height: 75px;

  float: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 14px; }

.bt-active a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid gold; }

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }

.maincontainer {
  height: 700px; }

.textheader {
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 180px;
  font-family: NexaLight;
  font-size: 48px; }

.ongoing-header {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #bcc0c1; }

.subheader {
  height: 70px;
  width: 260px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left; }

.subheader-menu {
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #ccd0d1; }

.button {
  height: 36px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s; }

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ecf0f1; }

.subheader-right {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
  width: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 24px; }

.ongoing-container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto; }

.ongoing-game {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  transition: 0.3s; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(even):hover {
  background-color: #f3f9fa; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background-color: #f3f9fa; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d3d9da; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dce0e1; }

.iconholder {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px; }

#username {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 24px; }

#btcamount {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 24px; }

#ongoing {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: left; }

.bitcoinlogo {
  height: 15px; }

.helpcontainer {
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

.helpform {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 12px; }

.helpform textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

#issuetext {
  height: 100px;
  width: 480px; }

#emailtext {
  height: 18px;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

.submitbutton {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s background-color; }

.submitbutton:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey; }
```

Comment: Well `urls` in CSS files are relative to the location of the file itself, right? So your `@include()` url likely needs to reflect that. You should check the error in devtools to see what `url` it is trying reach and update the `@include()` accordingly. For instance, I store my `font` files in a `font` directory like: `public/assets/fonts/` so I reference them in my `sass` files like: `fonts/name-of-font` since it's relative to the compiled file's path.

Comment: Well I tried updating my files path to the relative path, but that didn't fix my problem. the url in Chrome loa perfectly the font when i click on it, but i still get a 404 error.